# Wie fragt man "Wie wäre es mit ... 1 Uhr"?

Tags: preposition, idiom, time

Wie kann man eine Zeitangabe mit dem Ausdruck "wie wäre es mit" vorschlagen?

- "Wie wäre es mit um 1 Uhr?" -- zwei Präpositionen klingt seltsam an.
- "Wie wäre es mit 1 Uhr?" -- man riskiert die Antwort "gern, das ist eine schöne Uhr".

Answer (score 17):

> "Wie wäre es mit um 1 Uhr?"

Das klingt genau deshalb seltsam, weil es eben auch nicht richtig ist.

> "Wie wäre es mit 1 Uhr?"

Genau dies Formulierung ist korrekt und wird (zumindest gesprochen) auch richtig verstanden:

> "Wie wäre es mit **ein** Uhr"

Meinte man eine Armbanduhr, würde man doch sagen *"Wie wäre es mit **einer** Uhr"* oder *"..mit zwei **Uhren**"*. *"Uhr"* in der Uhrzeitangabe ist immer singular.

Alternativen sind, [wie zum Teil bereits erwähnt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/wie-fragt-man-wie-ware-es-mit-1-uhr/2205#2205):

> "Wie wäre es um eins?" - "Wie wäre es mit eins?" - "Passt es um eins?"

Comment: +1 for "Passt es um eins"

Comment: Eins ist bischen früh - wie wär's mit 2?

Comment: Having difficulty translating this...  Could you please clarify (in English) which of your 2nd and 3rd examples is correct?  Or is it that the 2nd example is correct, and the 3rd example is the way you would pronounce it?  Thanks!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: the first two examples were given by the OP. The third is correct (similar to the 2nd but **1** was written out to avoid confusion with **eins**). The bottom line gives three more commonly understood but more colloquial alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

Meine Vorschläge:

- "Wie wäre es mit Eins?" Wenn es in der Unterhaltung unmittelbar voher um das ausmachen einer Uhrzeiten ging, ist klar was gemeint ist. Auch gerne bei ungefähren Zeitspannen: "Was hältst du von Nachmittags|Abends|Morgends|Mittags?
- "Was hältst du von ein Uhr?"

Die Antwort "gern, das ist eine schöne Uhr" riskiert man auf jeden Fall bei keinem der Sätze - man fragt ja nicht "Wie wäre es mit **einer** Uhr?"

Comment: Danke! Kann man, auch wenn die Zeit anderes als Eins ist, "Uhr" weglassen? "Wie wäre es mit Zwei?" Außerdem: ist "mit Eins Uhr" falsch, oder geht beides?

Comment: "Eins Uhr" ist falsch. "Wie wäre es mit Zwei" würde ich nicht sagen; ich würde allerdings auch nicht "Wie wäre es mit Eins" sagen.

Comment: "Wie wäre es mit Eins|Zwei|...|Zwölf?" klingt in meine Ohren gut. Bei allem über Zwölf stellen sich mir ohne das "Uhr" dahinter die Nackenhaare auf. Für den Spezialfall 24:00 Uhr = 00:00 ginge noch "Wie wäre es mit Mitternacht(s)?" Was das "mit Eins Uhr" angeht, das ist falsh. Das "Uhr" wegzulassen ist in jedem Fall eher umgangssprachlich, aber ich höre es recht oft - besonders im süd- und mitteldeutschen Sprachraum.

Comment: @con-f-use: Im norddeutschen Sprachraum hört man das aber auch oft.

Answer (score 3):

A colloquial way of asking would be:

> Geht's bei dir um 1 (ein) Uhr?

Answer (score 2):

- "Wie wäre es mit Eins?" oder "Wie wäre es mit ein Uhr?" klingt holprig in meinen Ohren, ist aber sprachlich korrekt.
- "mit um Eins" ist falsch.
- gängig ist: "Was hältst Du von ein Uhr?"

Comment: Wie wär's denn mit um kurz nach Eins?