# Translation of "What/How about ...?"

Tags: usage, colloquial

> A: What time should we meet today?
>
> B: What/How about 6pm?

I wonder how people would say the "what/how about" part. I can't think of a good translation, and since it's a colloquial phrase, dictionary doesn't help much.

> A: Um wie viel Uhr sollen wir uns heute treffen?
>
> B: Was denkst du über 6pm?

Surely this doesn't sound natural ...

Comment: I just realized that this question is already [on GSE](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/wie-fragt-man-wie-ware-es-mit-1-uhr) pretty much (after I posted my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is a pretty idiomatic one:

> Wie wäre es mit...

So to say "How about 6pm?" you'd say

> Wie wäre es mit 18 Uhr?

You can, of course use this with things other than time.

> Wie wäre es damit, wenn Sie mich mal nicht unterbrechen würden?
>
> Wie wäre es mit Spinat?

Comment: Although this is pretty idiomatic, the penultimate example sounds quite long-winded and overblown (for being colloquial). You would probably rather say: "Wie wär's, wenn sie mich mal nicht unterbrechen würden?". Generally, even more "nonstandard" than "Wie wäre es mit...", you might just say "Wie wär(e)...", e.g. "Wie wär(e) 18 Uhr?". This is of course not to say, that the above translation is not perfectly right.